# A convergence in probability associated to order statistics

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution, order-statistics

Consider $n$ independent random variables $U_1,\dots,U_n$ uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$. Order them like so :
$$U_{(1)}\leq U_{(2)}\leq\cdots\leq U_{(n)}$$

> Let $x>0$ be given. How does one prove the following assertion :
> $$J_n=\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n\mathbf{1}_{\{n(U_{(k)}-U_{(k-1)})>x\}}\xrightarrow[n~\to~\infty]{~\text{in probability}~}e^{-x}~?$$
> (we set $U_{(0)}=0$).

---

What I have tried / observations :

- Since we are trying to establish convergence in probability to a constant, it suffices to show convergence in distribution ([see wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_of_convergence_of_random_variables#Convergence_in_distribution_to_a_constant_implies_convergence_in_probability))
- We can thus try to show either (a) pointwise convergence of the characteristic functions $\Phi_n=\Phi_{J_n}$ to $\Phi_{e^{-x}}$, or (b) pointwise convergence of the cumulative distribution functions $F_n=F_{J_n}$ to $F_{e^{-x}}$ at all points of continuity of the cumulative distribution function of the constant random variable $e^{-x}$, (that is, on $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{e^{-x}\}$)
- The $J_n$ only take on finitely many values that are non negative integers, and thus the $F_n$ only take on discrete values.
- The problem asks one to establish the fact that
  $$U_{(1)}\leq U_{(2)}\leq\cdots\leq U_{(n)})\sim\Big(\frac{T_{1}}{T_{n+1}},\dots,\frac{T_{n}}{T_{n+1}}\Big)$$
  with $T_k=\mathscr{E}_1+\cdots+\mathscr{E}_k$ with the $\mathscr{E}_i$, $i=1,\dots,n+1$ iid of exponential law of parameter $1$, aswell as the fact that
  $$nU_{(1)}\xrightarrow[n~\to~\infty]{~\text{in distribution}~}\mathrm{Exp. Law}(1)$$
- Another observation is the fact that convergence in probability is equivalent to convergence of $\mathbb{E}[|J_n-e^{-x}|\wedge 1]\to 0$, that is, since $-1\leq J_n-e^{-x}\leq +1$, $J_n\to e^{-x}$ in $L^1$.

The problem I don't know how to get rid of is fact that the $n(U_{(k)}-U_{(k-1)}$ aren't independent ... The facts I quote in the last bullet point entail that each $\mathbf{1}_{\{n(U_{(k)}-U_{(k-1)})>x\}}$ has the same expectation and they tend to $=e^{-x}$ as $n\to\infty$. Unfortunately the law of large numbers cannot be applied (and in any case, we are only asked to show convergence in probability anyways).

Answer (score 2):

Instead of studying the order statistics let us have a look on the lengths of the intervals between the order statistics: let
$$ L_i=U_{(i)}- U_{(i-1)} \qquad \text{for } 1\leq i\leq n+1,$$
where we use the convention that $U_{(0)}=0$ and $U_{(n+1)}=1$.
The random vector $(L_1,\dots,L_{n+1})$ has the uniform distribution on the simplex  $$ \left\{ (x_1,\dots,x_{n+1}) : x_1+\cdots+x_{n+1}=1, \quad x_1,\dots,x_{n+1}\geq 0 \right\}. $$

An alternative way to generate a random vector with this probability distribution is to consider the vector
$$ \left( \frac{Z_1}{Z_1+\cdots+Z_{n+1}}, \dots, \frac{Z_{n+1}}{Z_1+\cdots+Z_{n+1}} \right), $$
where $Z_1,\dots,Z_{n+1}$ are independent random variables with the exponential distribution $\operatorname{Exp}(1)$. (TODO: missing reference for the proof of this result.)

Our goal is to study the probability distribution of the number of indexes $k\in\{1,\dots,n\}$
with the property that $n L_k > x$ or, equivalently, the number $N$ of the indexes such that
$$ Z_k > x \cdot \frac{Z_1+\cdots+Z_{n+1}}{n}.$$
By Bienaymé-Chebyshev inequality the right-hand side converges in probability to $x$.

Take $\epsilon>0$ and denote by $N'$ the number of the indexes such that
$$ Z_k > x +\epsilon.$$
We have
$$ \mathbb{P}\left\{ N < N' \right\} \leq \mathbb{P}\left\{ x \cdot \frac{Z_1+\cdots+Z_{n+1}}{n} > x+\epsilon \right\} \xrightarrow{n\to\infty} 0.$$

Since the random events counted in $N'$ are independent, the law of large numbers implies that
$$ \frac{N'}{n} \xrightarrow{P} e^{-x-\epsilon}. $$

The union bound implies that
$$ \mathbb{P}\left\{ \frac{N}{n} < e^{-x -\epsilon} - \epsilon \right\} \leq  \mathbb{P}\left\{ N < N'\right\} + 
 \mathbb{P}\left\{ \frac{N'}{n} < e^{-x -\epsilon} - \epsilon \right\}   $$
converges to zero for each $\epsilon>0$.

Analogously one can show the upper bound that the probability of the event
$$ \frac{N}{n} > e^{-x +\epsilon} + \epsilon $$
converges to zero for each $\epsilon>0$.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I'll go over it in detail later today.

Answer (score 1):

You can find covariances of summands and show that they are (at least asymptotically) negative, and then use Chebyshev inequality. 
$$
\mathbb P\left(|J_n-e^{-x}|>2\varepsilon\right)\leq \mathbb P\left(|J_n-\mathbb E[J_n]|>\varepsilon\right)+\mathbb P\left(|\mathbb E[J_n]-e^{-x}|>\varepsilon\right)
$$
The second term is negligible, and the first one is bounded by
$$\mathbb P\left(|J_n-\mathbb E[J_n]|>\varepsilon\right)\leq \dfrac{\text{Var}(J_n)}{\varepsilon^2} = \dfrac{\text{Var}\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\mathbf{1}_{\{n(U_{(k)}-U_{(k-1)})>x\}}\right)}{n^2\varepsilon^2}
$$
Next,
$$
\text{Var}\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\mathbf{1}_{\{n(U_{(k)}-U_{(k-1)})>x\}}\right) = n\text{Var}\left(\mathbf{1}_{\{nU_{(1)}>x\}}\right) + n(n-1)\text{Cov}\left(\mathbf{1}_{\{n(U_{(k)}-U_{(k-1)})>x\}},\mathbf{1}_{\{n(U_{(j)}-U_{(j-1)})>x\}}\right)
$$
It seems too hard for me to find covariance but one simply can bound it from above: for $n>x$, 
$$
\mathbb P\left(n(U_{(k)}-U_{(k-1)})>x,\ n(U_{(j)}-U_{(j-1)})>x\right) = \mathbb P\left(\mathscr{E}_k - \frac{x}{n-x}\mathscr{E}_j > \frac{x}{n-x}T_{n+1}^{j,k},\;\mathscr{E}_j - \frac{x}{n-x}\mathscr{E}_k > \frac{x}{n-x}T_{n+1}^{j,k}\right):=P_1,
$$
where $T_{n+1}^{j,k}=T_{n+1}-\mathscr{E}_j-\mathscr{E}_k$.
The last probability is less than 
$$
P_1\leq \mathbb P\left(\mathscr{E}_k > \frac{x}{n-x}T_{n+1}^{j,k},\;\mathscr{E}_j - \frac{x}{n-x}\mathscr{E}_k > \frac{x}{n-x}T_{n+1}^{j,k}\right):=P_2
$$
and this probability can easily be found: 
$$
P_2=\int\limits_0^\infty \frac{y^{n-2}}{(n-2)!}e^{-y} \;\mathbb P\left(\mathscr{E}_k>y, \mathscr{E}_j > \frac{x}{n-x}(y+\mathscr{E}_k)\right)\,dy.
$$
I got 
$$
P_2=\frac1{2^{n-1}}\left(1-\frac{x}n\right)^n
$$
So, 
$$
\text{Cov}\left(\mathbf{1}_{\{n(U_{(k)}-U_{(k-1)})>x\}},\mathbf{1}_{\{n(U_{(j)}-U_{(j-1)})>x\}}\right)\leq \frac1{2^{n-1}}\left(1-\frac{x}n\right)^n - \left(1-\frac{x}{n}\right)^{2n}
$$
It is asymptotically strictly negative, and convergence in probability follows from Chebyshev inequality.

Comment: The fact that covariances should be negative seems to be sufficiently evident: the greater is the first indicator, the lower in an average is the second one. But it always seemed to me that the spacings are asymptotically independent, so the covariance should asymptotically vanish (being negative). The calculations show this is not the case, and I suppose some mistakes here.